# How to get html table row inside row in laravel using ui-sref?

Tags: html, angular, laravel, html-table

I have the code in angular to redirect to other page.

```
<div class="box-body no-padding">
  <table class="table table-condensed" id="example">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="payment in allPayments">
      <td><a  ui-sref="/MoneyIn({month: payment.year})">{{payment.year}}</a></td>
      <td>{{payment.amt}}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

On click of month it must get the row data which is in other html table just below the month which I have clicked.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Payment Date</th>
        <th>Payment Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="payment in allPayments">
        <td>{{payment.name}}</td>
        <td>{{payment.payment_date}}</td>
        <td>{{payment.amt}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the above table data to come below the month which is clicked.

Comment: Sorry I bit confused what you want to achieve. Can you provide a small demo in stackblitz?

Comment: I want similar to this "https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html". on click of + is shows below the data. same way on click of the month in ui-sref its row data should be seen below.

Comment: Ohkk so you using ui-sref to get the data? For display child table?

Comment: Yes on click of the link I must get the last table data which you can se with Name, date and amout just below the clicked month.